# Como mostrar los datos de solo los botones selecionados - Java JRadioButton

Tags: java, java-swing

Quisiera saber como mostrar la informacion de solo los botones selecionados por ejemplo seleciono el boton 1 y 2 pero el 3 no, pues eso lo que no he logrado comprender como hacerlo o talvez selecionando los botones 1 y 2 para que se muestre "como amigo".

```
class ventana extends Jframe {
JRadioButton boton1,boton2,boton3;
ventana(){
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setSize(762,456);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        botones();
}
public void botones(){
        boton1 = new JRadioButton();
        boton1.setBounds(200, 200, 20, 20);
        boton1.setText("Como");
        this.add(boton1);

        boton2 = new JRadioButton();
        boton2.setBounds(200, 235, 20, 20);
        boton2.setText("estas");
        this.add(boton2);

        boton3 = new JRadioButton();
        boton3.setBounds(200, 270, 20, 20);
        boton3.setText("Amigo");
        this.add(boton3);
}
}
```

este es la clase principal

```
public class ventanaP {

public static void main (String[]args){
ventana obj = new ventana();
obj.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: ¿en donde quieres escribir lo que seleccionas?

Comment: que se mostraran en un ciclo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres que al pulsar en un `JRadioButton` aparezaca su texto, o desaparezca al desmarcarlo, lo que quieres hacer realmente es realizar una acción cuando ocurra un evento, que en este caso es marcar o desmarcar el control.

En este sentido, tienes que saber que las interacciones que tienes con una interfaz Java Swing generan eventos, y tú puedes definir métodos que manejen ciertos tipos de eventos, y actuar en consecuencia.

La solución sería definir un manejador de eventos para cuando marques o desmarques el `JRadioButton`. Cuando lo marcas muestras el texto asociado, y cuando lo desmarcas, o bien haces el texto invisible, o lo sustituyes por una cadena vacía, o una cadena solo con espacios, o incluso puedes quitar el texto.

De manera conceptual quedaría así:

```
manejadorPulsacion() {
    if (hasMarcado) boton.setText("Texto");
    else boton.setText(null);
}
```

El manejador lo tienes que añadir a la lista de oyentes del botón, que contiene a todos los oyentes o interesados en escuchar los eventos que lanza el botón al interactuar con él.

```
boton.addListener(...);
```

Por supuesto, al añadir un oyente al botón, tienes que especificar qué tipo de evento va a manejar, y tienes que implementar la interfaz para ese tipo de oyente. En este caso el tipo de evento que se lanzará al pulsar en el control es `ActionEvent`, y necesitas un `ActionListener` para escuchar ese evento.

El control de si has marcado el control o lo has desmarcado lo puedes hacer gracias al método `isSelected` de la propia clase, es decir, no tienes que declarar más atributos o variables.

Más información:

- [`JRadioButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html)
- [`ActionEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html) y [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)
- [Implementar oyentes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)

Comment: muchas gracias!!